# Auth0 API Request

Tags: angular, auth0

I'm trying to make a `patch` request to my auth0 API endpoint, `myaccount.auth0.com/api/v2/users/:id`. I've set the headers to be `application/json`, but I still get the following error:

```
_body: "{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid request payload JSON format"}"
```

The request I made looks like this:

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
var data: any = {
    "app_metadata": {
        "ward": "99999"
    }
};

return this._http.patch('https://pjlamb12.auth0.com/api/v2/users/auth0|571844c894efdc0a5b6a4144', data, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
```

I matched the data I'm sending to the [docs like it shows here](https://auth0.com/docs/api/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id).

Why would I be getting this error when posting a JSON object like the docs show? What could I be missing?

Comment: Are you including an `Authorization` header in the request?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that I'm using angular2-jwt, so the this._http is an instance of AuthHttp.

Comment: Are you sure the `data` object is in correct JSON format in the body of the request?

Comment: I mean, I haven't checked in the call what it looks like, but the  `data` object above is correct JSON format.

Comment: The `data` object is a TypeScript `any` object.  The `body` parameter `patch` function expects type `string`.  You are not performing any string conversion on the object so it might be worth checking it's format in the actual request.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Originally I got an error because the endpoint expects an object, and I wasn't setting the `Content-Type` so it was converted to a string. So I got a `Bad Request` error then too but with a different reason.

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(data)` for the second parameter.

Comment: That seems to have worked. I tried it once but must have had something else wrong. Now I just have to get the APIv2 token correct and the cross origin settings fixed. Then I should be good. Thanks!

Comment: @pjlamb12 If the above solution worked please post the answer as reply yourself and mark it as the solution.