# Testing Auth0 API Patch Request

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, auth0, superagent

Trying to test Auth0 API patch request to modify user_metadata.
Using mocha and superagent for testing.

Get succeeds, but doing a patch with a userid and sending

```
.send({ "metadata": { "nickname": "Jill" } })
```

in the mocha testing file does not work.

```
router.patch('/:id', function(req, res, next) { 
  var options =  {
    method: 'PATCH',
    url: 'https://mrides.auth0.com/api/v2/users/' + req.params.id,
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + apiToken
    },
    data: req.body
  }
  request.patch(options, function(err, response, body) {
    if(!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.send(JSON.parse(body))
    } else {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  })
});
```

Error:

```
{
 "statusCode": 400,
 "error": "Bad Request",
 "message": "Payload validation error: 'Expected type object but found type null'.",
 "errorCode": "invalid_body"
}
```

Had seen this question:
[Auth0 API Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784721/auth0-api-request) 
but it did not work when trying:

```
data: JSON.stringify(req.body)
```

Any help or links on how to propery modify user_metadata?

Have also been looking through [Auth0 docs](https://auth0.com/docs/metadata/management-api) but no advancement yet.

Answer (score 0):

change options following way:

```
var options =  {
    method: 'PATCH',
    url: 'https://mrides.auth0.com/api/v2/users/' + req.params.id,
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + apiToken
    },

    // change here
    body: req.body
  }
  request.patch(options, function(err, response, body) {
    if(!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.send(JSON.parse(body))
    } else {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  })
};
```